# Why 6GB csv file is not possible to read whole to memory (64GB) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have csv file which sze is 6.8GB and I am not able to read it into memory into numpy array although I have 64GB RAM

CSV file has 10 milion of lines, each line has 131 records (mix of int and float)

I tried to read it to float numpy array

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('./data.csv', delimiter=';')
```

it failed due to memory.

when I read just one line and get size

```
data = np.genfromtxt('./data.csv', delimiter=';', max_rows=1)
data.nbytes
```

I get 1048 bytes
So , I would expect that 10.000.000 * 1048 = 10,48 GB which should be stored in memory without any problem. Why it doesn't work?

Finaly I tried to optimize array in memory by defining types

```
data = np.genfromtxt('./data.csv', delimiter=';', max_rows=1,
dtype="i1,i1,f4,f4,....,i2,f4,f4,f4")
data.nbytes
```

so I get only 464B per line, so it would be only 4,56 GB but it is still not possible to load to memory.

Do you have any idea?
I need to use this array in Keras.
Thank you

Comment: Based on [this](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-January/054522.html), just because the total memory amount may be available does not mean a continuous section large enough is.

Comment: you can use `fit_generator` to read and fit data batch-by-batch.

Comment: Are you running 32 bit Python?

Comment: @kazemakase it is 64-bit python, version 2.7.13

Comment: Ok. Would have been too easy ;)

Comment: @SandeepDcunha is it possible to shrink free memory somehow to be available for big array?

Comment: @user4206969 Memory is allocated by the OS, so memory allocation can't be messed with easily. As for increasing free memory blocks, you could try running fewer programs/tasks on your computer and just running the bare essentials. This will free up more memory and make it more likely that a large enough block of memory is free.

However, at this point, I'd recommend taking CtheSky's suggestion and  looking at batching, reading in rows in batches so only a portion of the csv is in memory at any one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`genfromtext` is regular python code, that converts the data to a numpy array only as a final step. During this last step, the RAM needs to hold a giant python list as well as the resultant numpy array, both at the same time. Maybe you could try `numpy.fromfile`, or the Pandas csv reader. Since you know the type of data per column and the number of lines, you also preallocate a numpy array yourself and fill it using a simple for-loop.